# Smooth atlas and extension of charts in a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold of dimension $m$.

a) Prove  that $M$ has a finite smooth atlas $A = \{(U_1, \varphi_1),...,(U_n, \varphi_n)\}$

b) Choose a smooth partition of 1, $\{θ_1,...,θ_n\}$ subordinate to $\{U_1,...,U_n\}$.
For each $j$ consider the function $\tilde \varphi_j: M\rightarrow \Bbb R^n $ given by $\tilde \varphi(p) = 0$ for every $p \in M\setminus U_j$  and $\tilde \varphi_j(p) =\theta_j(p)\varphi_j(p) $ for all $p \in U_j$. Prove that $\tilde \varphi_j$ is smooth for every $j$

My try:

a)$A_M = \{(U_i, \varphi_i),i\in I\}$ be the maximal smooth atlas of the manifold $M$ Because M is compact there exist a finite subcover given by $A = \{(U_1, \varphi_1),...,(U_n, \varphi_n)\}$ . This is  a finite smooth atlas, because the $\varphi_j, j \in I$ where initially smoothly compatible and this is just a subset of $A_M$, so also the  $\varphi_j, j \in \{1,..,n\}$ are smoothly compatible.

b) Let $A$ be as in (a). By definition of smooth partition of unity, $\theta_j: M \to \Bbb R$ is smooth and Supp$(\theta_j)\subseteq  U_j$ for every $j$. In particular $\theta_j$ is smooth over $ U_j$.The $\varphi_j:U_j \to \varphi_j(U_j)\subseteq\Bbb R^m $ are also smooth because they are diffeomorphisms. So the product
$\tilde \varphi_j(p)=\varphi_j(p)\theta_j(p)$ is smooth over $U_j$. Over $M\setminus U_j$ , $\tilde \varphi_j(p)=0$ so it is smooth over the interior Int$(M\setminus U_j)$. On the boundary $\partial (M\setminus U_j)$ it is also smooth because Supp$(\theta_j)\subseteq  U_j$, which means that for every point in that boundary there is an open  neighborhood where the $\tilde \varphi_j$ is 0.

**Is my solution OK? Am I missing something or is there anything to improve?**

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Actually, my phi tilde are defined outside U_j, it's in the statement of the problem

Comment: Maybe it was a typo that I fixed after you read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to make one point about the gluing argument for proving that $\tilde \varphi_j $ is smooth. (Otherwise, I think your proof is fine.)

The standard technique for this kind of gluing argument is to show that there exists an **open cover** $\{ V_\alpha \}$ of $M$ such that $f|_{V_\alpha}$ is smooth for each $\alpha$. If you can do this, then you'll have proved that $f$ is smooth on $M$. See Proposition 2.6 and Corollary 2.8 in Lee.

For our problem, let's consider the open cover $\{ V_1, V_2 \}$, where $V_1 = U_j$ and $V_2 = M \setminus \text{supp}(\theta_j)$.

- $\tilde \varphi_j$ is manifestly smooth on $V_1$, as you already observed.
- $\tilde \varphi_j$ is identically zero on $V_2$, and the zero function is smooth.

Comment: Are we using prop 2.6 or corollary 2.8 for this? I know that they are equivalent but, going by corollary 2.8. I think these would be the details:  I have the cover $\{V_1, V_2\}$, the smooth functions $F_1=\tilde\varphi_j |_{V_1}=\varphi_j:V_1\to \Bbb R^m$ and $F_2=\tilde\varphi_j|_{V_2}=0 : V_2\to \Bbb R^m$  and they agree on the overlap $V_1 \cap V_2$ where they are identically zero. Then there exists a unique smooth extension $F:M \to \Bbb R^m$ that has to be equal to $\tilde \varphi_j$ since it is unique as stated in the corollary.

Comment: @some_math_guy We can work this proof using either prop 2.6 or corollary 2.8. Your argument using corollary 2.8 is fine.