# Proving that I have an immersion in a (weak) version Whitney's embedding theorem for compact manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am proving a weak version of Whitney's embedding theorem for compact manifolds :

Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold of dimension $m$.

I can be  proven  that $M$ has a finite smooth atlas $A = \{(U_1, \varphi_1),...,(U_n, \varphi_n)\}$
Choose a smooth partition of 1, $\{θ_1,...,θ_n\}$ subordinate to $\{U_1,...,U_n\}$.
For each $j$ consider the function $\tilde \varphi_j: M\rightarrow \Bbb R^m $ given by $\tilde \varphi(p) = 0$ for every $p \in M\setminus U_j$  and $\tilde \varphi_j(p) =\theta_j(p)\varphi_j(p) $ for all $p \in U_j$. It can be proven  that $\tilde \varphi_j$ is smooth for every $j$

I have already proven these things and also that the smooth function $F:M \to \Bbb R^{n(m+1)}$

$F(p)=(\theta_1(p),...,\theta_n(p);\tilde \varphi_1(p),...,\tilde \varphi_n(p))$

is injective. I am having trouble proving that F is an immersion:

I can write $dF_p(X_p)=(X_pF^1,...,X_pF^{n(m+1)})$  ( as proven here

[$F(p)=(F_1(p),...F_r(p))$ smooth map, Why is it true that $dF_p(X_p)=(X_p(F_1),...,X_p(F_r))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805106/fp-f-1p-f-rp-smooth-map-why-is-it-true-that-df-px-p-x-pf-1/4805280#4805280)   )

So I just have to prove that the linear map  $dF_p$ has trivial Kernel:

If $0=dF_p(X_p)=(X_pF^1,...,X_pF^{n(m+1)})
= (X_p\theta_1,...,X_p\theta_n,X_p\tilde\varphi _1,...,X_p\tilde\varphi_n)$

$\implies X_p\theta_j=0 \tag 1$

and $X_p\tilde\varphi _j\tag 2=0$

for every $j=1,...n$

$0=X_p\tilde\varphi _j=X_p(\theta_j\varphi _j)=\varphi_j X_p\theta_j+\theta_jX_p\varphi_j = 0 + \theta_jX_p\varphi_j=\theta_jX_p\varphi_j$

I am not sure whether I should descent to a "pointwise level" here:

$0=\theta_j(p)X_p\varphi_j(p)$
If $\theta_j(p)\neq 0$,  then $X_p\varphi_j(p)=0$

But stil, **how can I conclude from here that $X_p$ is the $0$-derivation ?**

After that is proven, concluding that F is an embedding is straightforward because F is an immersion,smooth, bijective onto its image and it's a closed map (because a closed C set in M is compact , since M is compact, and F being continuous  implies F(C) is compact in a T2 space, therefore closed in F(M))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

Notice that $\theta_j(p) > 0$ for at least one choice of $j$. For this choice of $j$, $p$ is contained in the domain of the chart $\varphi_j : U_j \to \mathbb R^m$.

Let $x^1, \dots x^m$ be the coordinate functions associated with the chart $\varphi_j : U_j \to \mathbb R^m$. Then $\{ \left( \partial_{x^1} \right)_p, \dots , \left( \partial_{x^m} \right)_p \}$ is a basis for the tangent space at $p$ - which is to say that any $X_p$ can be written in the form $$ X_p = a^1 \left( \partial_{x^1}\right)_p + \dots + a^m \left( \partial_{x^m} \right)_p $$
for some choice of constants $a^1, \dots, a^n$.

Since the function $\varphi_j$ has the coordinate representation
$$ \widehat \varphi_j (x^1, \dots, x^m) = (x^1, \dots, x^m)$$
with respect to this chart,
we have
$$ \left( \partial_{x^1}\right)_p \varphi_j = (1, 0, \dots, 0),$$
$$ \left( \partial_{x^2}\right)_p \varphi_j = (0, 1, \dots, 0),$$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ \left( \partial_{x^m}\right)_p \varphi_j = (0, 0, \dots, 1).$$

So
$$ X_p  \varphi_j = (a^1, a^2, \dots, a^m).$$

If $X_p \varphi_j = 0$, then $a^1 = \dots = a^m = 0$, so $X_p = 0$, which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you meant m instead of n for consistency with my post since M has dim m.

Comment: On the other hand in Lee's book the coordinate repreentation $\hat \varphi_j$of  a function like $\varphi_j:U_j\to \Bbb R ^m $ is defined by composition with the inverse of a chart: $\psi_j: U_j\ \to  \Bbb R^m$, so $\hat \varphi_j=\varphi_j\circ \psi^{-1}$Are you taking $\psi_j=\varphi_j$?

Comment: Fix the $m$'s and $n$'s. Yes, I'm taking $\psi_j = \varphi_j$. I'll make that clear too

Comment: If you've got some minutes, could you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805071/smooth-atlas-and-extension-of-charts-in-a-compact-manifold?noredirect=1#comment10220320_4805071  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805106/fp-f-1p-f-rp-smooth-map-why-is-it-true-that-df-px-p-x-pf-1/4805280#4805280  They are the initial part of this question.  I just need some feedback to make sure I got it right.

Comment: @some_math_guy Done - just one small point about gluing arguments

Comment: Shouldn't the $\varphi_j$'s have hats after defining the coordinate representation?  I am unsure how to write $X_p\varphi_j$ using the coordinate representation $\hat\varphi_j$ since we have $X_p\varphi_j=0$ but we got $X_p\hat\varphi_j=0$

Comment: No, it's correct as written. $(\partial_{x^1})_p (\varphi_j) = \left(\partial_{x^1} \widehat{\varphi_j} \right) |_{\varphi_j(p)} = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$.